# Increase size of geom_point for one factor level

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I like to increase the `size` of only those data points where the factor variable `cyl == 6`. How can I do that?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = qsec , y = mpg, col = as.factor(cyl ))) +
  geom_point(size= 2)
```

[image]

I do not want to use the `size` option here:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = qsec , y = mpg, col = as.factor(cyl), size = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()
```

because it uses size for all factor levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to use `ifelse` to assign `size`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = qsec , y = mpg, col = as.factor(cyl), size = ifelse(cyl == 6, 4, 3))) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(size = 'none')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I like this very much. In my setup I use subsequent elements like `geom_smooth()` which picks up the size feature, thus producing a very thin and one thick smoothed line.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a column with the size for each factor and use size in `aes` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(size = case_when(cyl == 6 ~ 2,
                          TRUE ~1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = qsec , y = mpg, col = as.factor(cyl), size = size)) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(size = 'none')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use two data sets:

```r
ggplot() +
  aes(x = qsec, y = mpg, col = as.factor(cyl)) +
  geom_point(data = mtcars[mtcars$cyl != 6, ], size = 2) +
  geom_point(data = mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6, ], size = 5)
```

[image]